# Silence "No handlers could be found for logger "paramiko.transport"" Message

Tags: python, ssh, scripting, paramiko

As the title suggests, I would like to silence this warning message when running my python script. Does anyone have any suggestions? Google hasn't turnt up anything.

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you haven't configured logging for your root app and module doesn't know where to send log to. The simplest thing you can do is to use default config by adding to your app:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
```

See docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig)

Comment: Thank you, this works, the correct method is basicConfig() with camel case, just incase anyone was to complain.